# Restoring MySQL Databse informations by using edb files backedup

Tags: mysql, linux, edb

I am working actually in a company where we faced a big issue with our server and we needed to restore the Ubuntu server OS.
Before that we backed up all the tables contain in the database in .edb files extension.
Now I want your help in order to restore the backup tables in the new Database created after restoring the OS.
Thank in advance.

Comment: I have to say I would have proved that I could restore a backup before destroying the system! So how did you backup the MySQL database to .edb files?

Comment: What is an edb file? I see online "Exchange Database" but surely that is not Mysql.

Comment: Could it be that you did a standard backup and someone just decided to give the output file a silly extension? What is in one of the files, if its SQL it should be editable with a text editor

Comment: `mysql < filename.edb` should work. Linux doesn't care about extensions.